# Python: print all the string from list at the same time

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

For example, I have a list `a`. When I do it in a for loop, I can print all of its elements. But when I do it outside of the for loop, it only prints the last one. How can I print them all outside the for loop? Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
a=['a is apple','b is banana','c is cherry']
for i in a:
    print(i)
print("====================")
print(i)
```

It prints:

```
a is apple
b is banana
c is cherry
====================
c is cherry
```

What I want for the result is:

```
a is apple
b is banana
c is cherry
====================
a is apple
b is banana
c is cherry
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `print` with `*` and a separator of a newline:

```
print(*a, sep='\n')
print("====================")
print(*a, sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
a is apple
b is banana
c is cherry
====================
a is apple
b is banana
c is cherry
```

The `print(*a)` is equivalent to `print(a[0], a[1], a[2], ...)`.
This would print it with a white space in between.
Overriding this default with `sep='\n'` gives you a newline instead.

If you want to reuse it, write your own, small helper function:

```
def myprint(a):
    print(*a, sep='\n')

myprint(a)
```

A one-liner alternative, but arguably less readable:

```
print(*(a + ["=" * 20] + a), sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
a is apple
b is banana
c is cherry
====================
a is apple
b is banana
c is cherry
```

In Python 2 "turn on" the Python-3-style print function with:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Comment: Awesome! i will mark this as an answer. Just a question, I would like to set is to a variable like this b=(*a, sep='\n'), but it doesn't work. Thanks!

Comment: `print()` retunrs `None` and causes a side effect. Therefore, you cannot bind it the way you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `join()` and pass list to it as follows:

```
a=['a is apple','b is banana','c is cherry']
print("\n".join(a))
print("====================")
print("\n".join(a))
```

output

```
a is apple
b is banana
c is cherry
====================
a is apple
b is banana
c is cherry
```

Answer (score 1):

You can multiply list by 2 and append separator in middle of the list and then simply print the list using `join` method.

```
l = ['a is apple','b is banana','c is cherry']
l = l*2 
#['a is apple', 'b is banana', 'c is cherry', 'a is apple', 'b is banana', 'c is cherry']
l = l.insert(int(len(l)/2), '====================')
#['a is apple', 'b is banana', 'c is cherry', '====================','a is apple', 'b is banana', 'c is cherry']
print('\n'.join(l))
```

This will output:

```
a is apple
b is banana
c is cherry
====================
a is apple 
b is banana
c is cherry
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. This will give what you need

```
x,y,z=a
print(x,y,z)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest and cleanest way of doing it (universal across Python 2 and 3):

```
print('\n'.join(a + ["===================="] + a))
```

This is the Python-3-only version:

```
print(*(a + ["===================="] + a), sep='\n')
```